# Agrupar registros de una tabla por año - Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo la siguiente duda al hacer una consulta en MySql y PHP.

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MYSQL bajo el nombre de **"SERVICIOS"**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que deseo realizar es una consulta que me agrupe todos los registros por año, es decir me muestre todos los registros del 2018, 2019, etc con toda la información que le pertenece a cada registro y luego imprimirlo en una tabla HTML con php.

Estuve buscando soluciones e intentando realizar consultas, pero no he obtenido el resultado que quiero.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**Agurpación**

Sin funciones de agregación.

> Agrupas columnas que tienen valores en común que ayudan a formar subgrupos de registros, la regla para agrupar la dan los valores que existen en el `SELECT`; es decir todas las columnas ahí listadas deben ser susceptibles de agrupamiento por valores en común.
>   Lo anterior para que por ejemplo 3 renglones se fusionen en uno solo para evitar visualizar valores de columnas repetidos.

En tu muestra de datos, aunque existen posible sub grupos de fechas por la columna `sg_fecha_servicio`, sin embargo se presentan los siguientes casos:

- La fecha: `2018-02-01` puede formar un solo grupo, sin embargo estas mismas 3 filas con dicha fecha tienen **monto diferente** e **identificador diferente**

Por ejemplo:

**Código 1**

Seleccionando únicamente la fecha y el cliente, obtenemos un total de 5 filas así:

```
SELECT fecha, cliente
FROM version
GROUP BY fecha, cliente
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Con esta salida:

```
fecha       cliente
2019-02-06  CL-001
2019-02-03  CL-001
2019-02-01  CL-001
2018-12-31  CL-002
2018-02-01  CL-002
```

**Código 2**

Si ahora empezamos a agregar mas columnas en el `SELECT` y por ende en el `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT fecha, cliente, chofer, monto
FROM version
GROUP BY fecha, cliente, chofer, monto
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Obtenemos una salida de 7 filas, por lo ya expuesto anteriormente

```
fecha       cliente chofer     monto
2019-02-06  CL-001  729993      700
2019-02-03  CL-001  44062728    700
2019-02-01  CL-001  44062728    500
2018-12-31  CL-002  44062728    500
2018-02-01  CL-002  729993      100
2018-02-01  CL-002  44062728    400
2018-02-01  CL-002  44062728    500
```

Si ahora eliges en tu consulta todas las columnas, de este modo:

```
SELECT fecha, cliente, vehiculo, monto, identificador
FROM version
GROUP BY fecha, cliente, vehiculo, monto, identificador
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Da como salida esto:

```
fecha      cliente  vehiculo    monto   identificador
2019-02-06  CL-001  5            700    SAB-4
2019-02-03  CL-001  11           700    SAB-6
2019-02-01  CL-001  1            500    SAB-3
2018-12-31  CL-002  1            500    SAB-0
2018-02-01  CL-002  1            400    SAB-1
2018-02-01  CL-002  2            100    SAB-2
2018-02-01  CL-002  11           500    SAB-5
```

Lo cual no es una agrupación como tal, pues si observas se visualizan registros repetidos en varias columnas, lo cual se origina de que existen valores que no se pueden agrupar por ser distintos.

La anterior salida, sería lo mas próximo a `AGRUPAMIENTO` que posterior puedes recorer con PHP y imprimirlo en tu HTML.

**Con funciones de agregación**

Una opción que se me ocurre es que hagas un `SUM` del monto por cliente así aunque sean valores distintos al ser de la misma fecha se suman y redfucen a un sola fila, finalmente hagas un `GROUP_CONCAT` de todos los identificadores por fecha así:

```
SELECT fecha, GROUP_CONCAT(cliente) AS Clientes, 
       SUM(monto) AS Total, GROUP_CONCAT(identificador) AS Identificadores
FROM version
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Teniendo esta salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aunque aclaro que no se si una suma de los montos es lo que buscas exactamente